# How to load webpage as response to request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I would like to load a webpage in response to a request for a path,I have figured it out till here:

```
var http=require('http');
var mysql=require('./mysql');
var fs=require('fs');
var app=http.createServer();
app.listen(8000);

app.on('request',function(req,res){
var _path=req.url;
if(path==='/')
{   res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World \n');
}
if(path==='/demo')
{
    //this is bad,we could use streams to improve this(although this is non-blocking too)
    fs.readFile('../maps/google_maps.html',function(err,contents){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log('did not work');
            res.writeHead(500);
        }
        else
        {
            res.setHeader("Content-Length", contents.length);
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.write(contents);
        }
        res.end();
    });
}
});
```

Server does not work for /demo path,it throws the error:

```
 { [Error: ENOENT, open '../maps/google_maps.html'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: '../maps/google_maps.html' }
```

Comment: What doesn't work or where are you stuck?

Comment: `console.log` out to see what your actual `path` is

Comment: You set your path with an underscore but then the one you use does not have an underscore.

Comment: noticed and fixed that path / works,i am looking for /demo,it does not load the webpage,fs.readFile throws error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var _path=req.url;
if(path==='/')
```

you create `_path` but then compare `path`, which is always undefined

change it to `var path=req.url;`

error:
`ENOENT` means file not found
`../maps/google_maps.html` is a path relative to where you're calling `node` from, so make sure file exists, or specify full path

To make a path relative to the script, you must use the `__dirname` variable.

```
__dirname + '/path/to/file'
```

Comment: Just gunna use my comment as an answer like that eh?

Comment: @Thunda actually only saw your comment after posted my answer

Comment: noticed and fixed that path / works,i am looking for /demo,it does not load the webpage,fs.readFile throws error.

Answer (score 0):

You should better use [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) along with *Jade* which is a templating engine for Node.js. You can easily render html pages to client and serve static content

Comment: Will check it out,also are there any alternatives to socket.io for communicating with the client.

Comment: Sockjs is another popular alternative to socket.io. Google it and you'll find more